# Resource ... is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

If i try to use this action (test2) it always returns "The requested resource (/WebApplication4/newFolder/test2.jsp) is not available."

Running tomcat6 and netbeans 6.7.1

config.xml (it is **included** in struts.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="mypackage" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="test2">
            <result>/newFolder/test2.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/87/b7/dc/1676731/0/clipboard4.jpg](http://img2.pict.com/87/b7/dc/1676731/0/clipboard4.jpg)

but if i change result value from "/newFolder/test2.jsp" to "test.jsp" - everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, needed:

```
<result>/WEB-INF/newFolder/test2.jsp</result>
```